# Connection timeout over VPN

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I have a Java program that connects to SQL Server with mssql-jdbc driver. But some users use this program over VPN and the last days we are having issues with that VPN that is causing slowness. When I ping the machine that have the SQL instance returns a 1800ms ping. Last week this ping was 400~600ms.
When the ping is above 800ms Java returns a timeout to me, so the users using VPN can not connect.

I have tried to set up a higher login timeout in Java connection string to 10 minutes for testing, but even with that the connection always return a timeout. This only happens when the ping is above 800ms so I do not think the problem can be ports, firewall or something like that.

```java
//my connection code
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(60); //setting up my timeout to 60 seconds
private static final String CONNSTRING = "jdbc:sqlserver://server-name\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=db_name;"; //my connection string
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNSTRING, USER, PASS);
```

Maybe there is another property that I can add to my connection string to solve that problem? Or something that I can set up in SQL Server to allow this connection when the VPN is slow?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried `;loginTimeout=60` in the connection string itself? This only affects the timeout during the login process. There are other connection-related timeouts, such as socketTimeout. IDbCommand has a CommandTimeout property, which in JDBC is set via PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout().

Comment: Does the timeout happen during connect? If not, then the `loginTimeout` will not fix your problem. It might also be helpful for us to post the exception stacktrace when the timeout occurs.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel These weekend our VPN was stable, so I could not get the stack trace. But 10 minutes ago we got this timeout again. 
Stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/cAfDHqUw

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I also tried this today and I got the same error

Comment: You need to add it to your question (inline, not with a link).